# Multivariable implicit Differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $x^3+y^3+8$ using partial derivative

So what I need to do is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and  $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ which are:

$3x^2$ and $3y^2$ and than to divide to get ${\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\over \frac{\partial}{\partial y}}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but sign should be also correct, see how the negative sign comes in.

Let  $$ u=x^3+y^3+8$$

By two variable implicit differentiation at constant $u$ , $ du =0 $

$$ du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} dy = 0 $$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= - \dfrac  {\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}} {\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}} = -\dfrac{3 x^2}{3 y^2}= -\dfrac{ x^2}{ y^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that this is for $f=x^3+y^3+8=0$ and not for $f=x^3+y^3+8$.

So $f'_x=3x^2$, $f'_y=3y^2$ and, by the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), $$\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac {f'_x}{f'_y}=-\frac{x^2}{y^2}$$

Comment: @Why there is minus?

Comment: @newhere.  Look at Narasimham's details.